# Limit of a sequence $(1+1/n)^{(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have to find the limit of a sequence $(1+1/n)^{(1+n)}$. Any help is most welcome.

Comment: I assume you want the limit as $n \to \infty$. Are you familiar with $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+ \dfrac1n \right)^n = e?$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: It is $e$.Power $(n+1)$ doesn't change anything in the limit given by Marvis.

Comment: $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n + 1} = (1 + \frac{1}{n})(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but a big hint: do you agree that
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} =  \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \ ?
$$
As $n \to +\infty$, can you read a very famous limit on the right-hand side? The other term won't do you any harm, since it converges to ...

Comment: Thanks Siminore! Yes I know the famous limit and now this one becomes very simple to compute.

Answer (score 2):

Use 
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} =\exp\left((n+1)\log(1+\frac{1}n)\right)
$$
and look at the limit for the exponent:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left((n+1)\log(1+\frac{1}n)\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log(1+\frac{1}n)}{\frac{1}{n+1}}=\frac{0}{0}
$$
so we can try L'Hospitâl and get
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{1+1/n}}{-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+1}{n}=1.
$$
Therefore your limit is $e^1$.

Comment: As I always remark: you need to apply De l'Hospital to the formal extension of the given sequence to the set of real numbers. It may seem a pedantic issue, but it isn't.

Comment: thanks draks!  I got the point

Comment: @Siminore: Can you elaborate a bit more? I didn't understand your point... Thanks

Comment: @Siminore do you mean, one should mention that $n$ is element of the [Extended real number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\Bbb{R}\cup \pm \infty$?

Comment: It is a trivial fact, and I know that many users don't like it. I just mean that you cannot apply De l'Hospital to a sequence $a_n/b_n$. You can if you know that $a_n=f(n)$ and $b_n=g(n)$, where $f$ and $g$ satisfy De l'Hospital's theorem. In this case it is clear. But I have seen things, as a teacher, that you cannot imagine :-) I've seen differentiation of $(-1)^n$ with respect to $n$, for instance.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dn}(-1)^n=\frac{d}{dn}e^{i\pi n}= i\pi (-1)^n$

Comment: @Siminore did you downvote, because of my last comment? It was meant as fun.

Comment: Don't worry, I appreciate irony! :-)